# Singleton on weblogic 10.3

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, jms, weblogic

we are trying to find a good solution for creating a singleton on weblogic.

Right now we have an ear that is deployed both in a clustered environment and single server. Within the ear is a singleton that holds some state. Duplicating that state over 2 servers would lead to incorrect behavior. Currently that singleton is only accessed though an MDB that is deployed as max 1. That MDB is listening to a topic. The topic is not distributed which leads to us having it on only one server, but resulting in warnings on the deployment which we don't like.

We've considered a couple of solutions:

- Weblogic's SingletonService. Works ok, but it works on clusters only leading to issues for single server versions of the application and for developer sandboxes.
- Creating a separate ear for the singleton and surrounding code and deploying it on a separate managed server. That is expected to work as required, but will require a substantial amount of work to decouple our singleton from surrounding code and require us to expose a lot of functionality to remote access.
- Making singleton stateless removing the singleton requirement. Should work, but again, would require a lot of work

Are there other ways to resolve the issue? Maybe some JMS trick?

Comment: A clarification: The singleton is an event processor with logic like: "do foo every 3rd bar that satisfies baz. The counting is what creates the requirement for it to be a singleton. Both foo and baz require interaction with the rest of the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would creating a shared library work? The shared library can have a singleton.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/libraries.html#wp1071514
https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/weblogic_server_shared_librari_1

Comment: Putting the singleton in the shared library is unlikely to work since there will still be one of those for each server in a cluster. 

But it might make it easier to put the singleton into a non-clustered server and make all the code common for the singleton and other stuff into a shared library. I'll need to play around with this...

Comment: You may also look at coherence as a way to share data between instances.

Answer (score 2):

Pavel, I see you already come up with many great ideas yourself. It looks like you need a singleton cross cluster to do the counting. The singleton you need does not have to be an in-memory singleton.  You can move the count to a database table. The database table can act as a singleton.  Whenever the count is increased, you make a jdbc call to update the count field in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I have understand very well your problem, maybe the most easy solution is make the topic distributed and use it to propagate the singleton state to all the cluster nodes.

You can use the topic to propagate the singleton state, I mean, Have only one singleton state, on changes or behaviours that need an implicit reload, send a message to the topic, every MDB subcribe to the topic will receive the message (here the distributed is the trick) (for example, one MDB for cluster node) and act as you need in every node.

hope this help, but again I don´t know if I understand well your issue.

Comment: There is too much logic within the singleton requiring access to surrounding code for this to be a simple solution.  The singleton is processing events and actions caused by events are dependent on system state (a bunch of database reads with some logic in between). It's doable to make all those checks MDB driven, but it would require a lot of work and will probably wreck havoc on performance